# Get image Uri + thumbnail of the picture shot with camera in Android

Tags: android, camera, uri, photo

I want to update an ImageView with a picture I make with the build-in Android camera.
I use the following code:

```
void getPhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
```

After that I acquire the photo with:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView photoView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoId);
            photoView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }
```

But with this code no matter what I do I only get a thumbnail of the photo I made - my question is how can I get the Uri of the photo just made in order to work not with the thumbnail but with the original image?

Ps. I actually need the thumbnail of the photo but I need the Uri of the original photo too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put my own URI in the intent to tell it where to save, then you know where it is, not sure there is any other way. 
Create some fields for your file.

```
private String imagePath = "/sdcard/Camera/test.jpg";
private File originalFile;
```

Then initialize the file.

```
originalFile = new File(imagePath);
```

Now start the Camera app with the intent, passing the URI as an extra.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(originalFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

In the onActivityResult() extract the URI

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalImagePath, BitmapFactoryOptions);  //set whatever bitmap options you need.
```

So you can now build a bitmap using createBitmap or use file path for whatever you need

Comment: Also it's not good practice to hard code the uri with /sdcard/, you should use getter for the environment variables.

Comment: But the data intent is null, you cannot retrieve thumbnail. You just can create it from full size photo