# How to get Image

Tags: android

I am new in Android and have very small issue, i want to know what code i need to use to get image.

like if we use this to get text :

```
name = txtname.getText().toString();
```

**So what we use to get Image ?**

*CODE:*

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_IMAGEURL = "imageurl"

String name, image ;

Intent in = getIntent();
String mname = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
String mimage = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGEURL);

ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

final ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
final TextView txtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

txtn.setText(mname);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(mimage, imgv);

name = txttitle.getText().toString();
image = // here i want to know what i should need to use to get image 
         // like i am getting text using :::txttitle.getText().toString();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257573/get-image-uri-thumbnail-of-the-picture-shot-with-camera-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473823/android-get-image-from-gallery-into-imageview

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/09/13/android-how-to-get-an-image-via-an-intent/

Comment: String name, image ; you should change the Type of image to Bitmap or something meaningful

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView.getDrawable()` will return the `Drawable` set in an `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

if you've used `setImageDrawable()` to set image to the ImageView then you can use `imgv.getDrawable()` method to get the image.